# How to concat fields form table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have table name data and field is:

- id
- kode
- prov_nama
- kota_nama
- bus
- kode_d (field concat)

i use PHPMaker and my followed code is 
CONCAT (upper(substr(kota_nama,1,2)),kode) 
example :

- id: 1
- kode: 001
- prov_nama: Jakarta
- kota_nama: Cijantung
- Bus:VIP

The output **kode_d** is : **CI001**

How to make output **kode_d** like : **JCI001**
with concat

Concatenated string = [First character of prov_nama][First two characters of kota_nama][kode]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add the first character of prov_nama

`CONCAT(part1, part2, part3, ..., partn)`

`upper(string)` --> To capital case

`substr(string, start_index, number_of_characters)`

`CONCAT(upper(substr(prov_nama,1,1)),upper(substr(kota_nama,1,2)),kode)`